# Preventing bots from accessing website hosted on GCloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, robots.txt

I am trying to prevent all search engines bots from accessing my website.

I read that these permissions can be specified to robots.txt file but I am not sure where to access this file in order to edit it on Google Cloud.

I developed my web server using Python with Gcloud.

Note that I read the following topic
http://stocksonfire.in/seo/edit-robots-txt-google-cloud-solved/
However, I did not find any VM instance in my resources.
Do I need to create one first?

edit: This is my app.yaml file after appling @Dac Saunders suggestion

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

handlers:
- url: /robots\.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots\.txt
```

Comment: Side note: you can't really prevent robots from accessing the site using `robots.txt`, misbehaving ones may choose to ignore the file. See http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/blockjustbad.html.

Answer (score 2):

My `robots.txt`(with python appengine) looks like this.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /q?

Sitemap: /sitemap.xml.gz
```

I placed it in `<MYAPP>/static/robots.txt`. Then I mapped it in `app.yaml` like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /(robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*
```

This way my robots.txt becomes accessible in the root of my domain.

Comment: I tried adding the following lines to robots.txt

handlers:
- url: /robots\.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots\.txt

robots.txt exists in the same folder as app.yaml.
I couldn't follow your format since I don't have a favicon.ico nor do I know what is <MYAPP>/static/

Comment: I am still unable to access the file when I write MYWEBSITE/robots.txt

Comment: Can you edit your question to show app.yaml as it currently looks? It's not clear whether you added the lines specifically about robots.txt or replaced what is currently in the question. If you just added lines below what you posted, the existing stuff (`url: /(robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)`) would match first and probably prevent your additions from being evaluated.

Comment: app.yaml file has been included in the question